# (C++) Dereferenced pointer returns correct value when called within same class, and 0 when called from main

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to take a periodical snapshot of some objects used. To achieve this I use the TakeSnapshot() method, which works like this:

1. The gamemanager that calls the TakeSnapshot() has a list of pointers to the objects I'd like to save (std::list objects;) It iterates trough the pointers, dereferences them and makes a new Object of same type that copies the values I'm interested in.
2. After it's copied, the new object is pushed onto a vector and a new GameState object is created (gamestate is the 'snapshot').
3. then it stores the vector in the new GameState object and pushes the GameState object into a queue of gamestates, if the size of queue is over some predetermined amount it is discarded in FIFO fashion.

what I'm having problems with is that for later calculations for the game I will require to have a working pointer to the latest snapshot of the game. I tried to store it in a public GameState* but when I dereference it from the Main function it doesn't return the correct values (?). But if I try to dereference it inside the TakeSnapshot(), it returns the correct values

**FPS.cpp**

```
// FPS.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

class GameState {
    public:
        std::vector<Object> objects;
};

class GameManager {     
    public:
        int tick = 0;
        int tickrate = 150;
        int memorySize = tickrate;

        std::list<Object*> objects;
        std::queue<GameState> snapshots;

        GameState * latestSnapshot;

    void AddObject(Object* object) {
        objects.push_back(object);
    }

    void TakeSnapshot() {
        GameState snapshot;
        std::vector<Object> objectsCopy;
        std::list<Object*>::const_iterator it;
        for (it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it) {
            Object copyObject;
            copyObject.position = (*it)->position;
            objectsCopy.push_back(copyObject);
        }

        snapshot.objects = objectsCopy;

        latestSnapshot = &snapshot;
        snapshots.push(snapshot);
        if (snapshots.size() > memorySize) {
            snapshots.pop();
        }
        cout << (*latestSnapshot).objects.size() << endl; // <--- RETURNS 2 
    }
};



int main(){
    GameManager gameManager;

    Object player;
    Object player2;
    player.position = Vector(154, 0, 0);

    gameManager.AddObject(&player);
    gameManager.AddObject(&player2);

    GameState latestSnapshot = *gameManager.latestSnapshot;
    cout << latestSnapshot.objects.size() << endl;// <--- RETURNS 0 
}
```

*Edit* only left the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Can you please remove all the irrelevant code and narrow that down to a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: On your function `TakeSnapshot()` the variable `GameState  snapshot` is destroyed at the end of the function. and then the pointer `latestSnapshot` no longer points to a valid object. When you call it on your main function via `GameState latestSnapshot = *gameManager.latestSnapshot` here the object that `latestSnapshot` pointed to no longer exists (lives on the stack).

Comment: oh i see, so i would have to make the pointer point at the last value in the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tesseractBird said, the error was caused because the pointer pointed to an object that was destroyed, making it point at the last value i added to the queue solved the problem.